# How to add variable into div tag name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a variable into the name of my dynamically generated div tag. Here is what I have for the div

```
var level4_div = "<div class=\"level4_main text\" style=\"overflow: hidden; clear: both; background-color: #E6E6E6; margin: 5px 0 5px 50px; padding: 5px;\"><div style=\"float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;\"><b>Safety Verification Method:</b></div><div style=\"float: left;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"field_\" id=\"field_\" size=\"35\" /></div></div>";
```

And instead of having it say "Safety Verification Method" each time, I want it to say "Safety Verification Method 1.1.1" with the values incrementing. I already have the values incrementing in a stored variable called 'field'. S

```
<b>"'+field+'"Safety Verification Method:</b></div>
```

but it kept returning me errors.

EDIT:
To rephrase the question, since I generate the div tag in the beginning and create the index variable after, how can I update it that way; similar to

```
$(level3_div).appendTo(level3_parent).find("input").attr("name",level2_id+"-"+index_3).attr("id",level2_id+"-"+index_3);
```

except for the display name rather than the id.

Full Source Code

```
var spacer = "<div style=\"clear: both; height: 1px;\"></div>";                           

var level2_div = "<div class=\"level2_main text\" style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; clear: both; padding: 5px;\"><div style=\"float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;\"><b>Level 2:</b></div><div style=\"float: left;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"field_\" id=\"field_\" size=\"35\" /></div><div style=\"float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"addlevel3\">Add Hazard Control</a></div></div>";

var level3_div = "<div class=\"level3_main text\" style=\"overflow: hidden; clear: both; background-color: #F6F6F6; margin: 5px 0 5px 25px; padding: 5px;\"><div style=\"float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;\"><b>Hazard Controls:</b></div><div style=\"float: left;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"field_\" id=\"field_\" size=\"35\" /></div><div style=\"float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"addlevel4\">Add Safety Verification Method</a></div></div>";

var level4_div = "<div class=\"level4_main text\" style=\"overflow: hidden; clear: both; background-color: #E6E6E6; margin: 5px 0 5px 50px; padding: 5px;\"><div style=\"float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;\"><b>Safety Verification Method:</b></div><div style=\"float: left;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"field_\" id=\"field_\" size=\"35\" /></div></div>";

var index_2 = 16;
$("#container").on('click','.addlevel2', function() {
    $(level2_div).insertAfter(".level2_main:last").find("input").attr("name","field_"+index_2).attr("id","field_"+index_2);
    index_2++;

    return false;
});

var index_3 = 1;
$("#container").on('click','.addlevel3', function() {
    var level3_parent = $(this).parents(".level2_main");
    var level2_id = $(level3_parent).find("input").attr("id");
    var div3_exists = $(level3_parent).find('.level3_main');
    var div3_count = $(div3_exists).length;
    var level3_counter = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden_\" id=\"hidden\" />";

    if (div3_count == "0") {
        index_3 = 1;
        $(level3_counter).appendTo(level3_parent).attr("name","hidden_"+level2_id).attr("id","hidden_"+level2_id).attr("value",index_3);
        $(spacer).appendTo(level3_parent);
        $(level3_div).appendTo(level3_parent).find("input").attr("name",level2_id+"-"+index_3).attr("id",level2_id+"-"+index_3);

    } 
    else 
    {
        index_3 = div3_count + 1;
        $("#hidden_"+level2_id).attr("value",index_3);    
        $(level3_div).appendTo(level3_parent).find("input").attr("name",level2_id+"-"+index_3).attr("id",level2_id+"-"+index_3);
    }
    index_3++;
    console.log(index_3);
    return false;
});
```

EDIT #2:

What I am trying to do is change each individual dynamically generated div tags name, not just the first version. For example, the first div tag would read "Hazard Control 1" and the next one generated would read "Hazard Control 2" and so on while the original "Hazard Control 1" remained that way and did not change.

HTML

```
<left><div class="tabs" align="left">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">VTL</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" align="left">

        <div id="container" style="width: 90%; border: 1px solid #000;">


    <div class="level2_main text" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; clear: both; padding: 5px;">

      <div style="float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;"><b>Hazard Cause #1:</b></div>

      <div style="float: left;">

        <input type="text" name="field_1" id="field_1" size="35" />

      </div>

      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;"><a href="#" class="addlevel3">Add Hazard Control</a></div>

    </div>

    <div class="level2_main text" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; clear: both; padding: 5px;">

      <div style="float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;"><b>Hazard Cause #2:</b></div>

      <div style="float: left;">

        <input type="text" name="field_2" id="field_2" size="35" />

      </div>

      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;"><a href="#" class="addlevel3">Add Hazard Control</a></div>

    </div>

    <div class="level2_main text" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; clear: both; padding: 5px;">

      <div style="float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;"><b>Hazard Cause #3:</b></div>

      <div style="float: left;">

        <input type="text" name="field_3" id="field_3" size="35" />

      </div>

      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;"><a href="#" class="addlevel3">Add Hazard Control</a></div>

    </div>

    <div class="level2_main text" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; clear: both; padding: 5px;">

      <div style="float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;"><b>Hazard Cause #4:</b></div>

      <div style="float: left;">

        <input type="text" name="field_4" id="field_4" size="35" />

      </div>

      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;"><a href="#" class="addlevel3">Add Hazard Control</a></div>

    </div> 
    <div class="level2_main text" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden; clear: both; padding: 5px;">

      <div style="float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;"><b>Hazard Cause #5:</b></div>

      <div style="float: left;">

        <input type="text" name="field_5" id="field_5" size="35" />

      </div>

      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;"><a href="#" class="addlevel3">Add Hazard Control</a></div>

    </div> 

    <div><input type="hidden" name="leveltwototal" id="leveltwototal" value="6" size="35" /></div>

  </div>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's the error message you are getting? Also do you want the values to increment 1.1.1 to 1.1.2 and so on?

Comment: Based on the level of depth in the list, it increments either 1.1.1 -> 1.1.2 or 1.1.1 -> 1.2.1. The issue is that I created the div tag in the beginning and have the variable of the integer values in a method after. So whenever I try to update the div name as such, it returns the error saying that the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: I suggest you to move the styles to a CSS file

Comment: I suggest you post your html code too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an empty `span` where you want your dynamic text to appear.
And then change the content of this span.

```
var level3_div = "<div class=\"level3_main text\" style=\"overflow: hidden; clear: both; background-color: #F6F6F6; margin: 5px 0 5px 25px; padding: 5px;\"><div style=\"float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;\"><b>Hazard Controls:</b></div><div style=\"float: left;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"field_\" id=\"field_\" size=\"35\" /></div><div style=\"float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"addlevel4\">Add Safety Verification Method<span class=\"safety-verification-counter\"></span></a></div></div>";
```

And when the button is clicked I added this line of code to target the corresponding `span` element.

```
 $("#"+level2_id+"-"+index_3).parent().next().find('.safety-verification-counter').text(' 1.1.'+index_3);
```

Here is the working example based on your code

https://jsfiddle.net/tpdm688o/3/

Comment: Yes but how can I add the number value after running the function as my code is doing shown above

Comment: just use an empty span where you want to put your text

Comment: It kind of solved the issue, however the empty span was in the original div tag. So whenever it was changed, it would simply change that one only, not the newly generated div tag

Comment: It does generate the span tag for each individual dynamically generated div tag; however, it only updates the first empty span.

Comment: It was a generic example....I updated the code based on your code and the html you provided

Answer (score 0):

If you use single and double quotes you can avoid having to escape so many of them. Here it is rewritten:

```
var level4_div = "<div class='level4_main text' style='overflow: hidden; clear: both; background-color: #E6E6E6; margin: 5px 0 5px 50px; padding: 5px;'><div style='float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;'><b>Safety Verification Method " + field + ":</b></div><div style='float: left;'><input type='text' name='field_' id='field_' size='35' /></div></div>";
```

Edit:

After seeing your changes you could do something like this to edit it after the fact.

```
$(level3_div).appendTo(level3_parent).find("input").attr("name",level2_id+"-"+index_3).attr("id",level2_id+"-"+index_3).children("b").html(index_3 + " Safety Verification Method:");
```

Comment: it still didn't end up changing the display name.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for your needs is to replace the part.

```js
var field = '1.1.1';
var level4_div = "<div class=\"level4_main text\" style=\"overflow: hidden; clear: both; background-color: #E6E6E6; margin: 5px 0 5px 50px; padding: 5px;\"><div style=\"float: left; width: 60px; padding-top: 5px;\"><b>Safety Verification Method:</b></div><div style=\"float: left;\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"field_\" id=\"field_\" size=\"35\" /></div></div>";

console.log(level4_div.replace('Safety Verification Method:', 'Safety Verification Method: ' + field));
```